# Update multiple array object in mongodb by sending Array of id using spring boot

Tags: java, arrays, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

New to mongodb  want to update document having multiple array inside that just by passing array of id

have some query idea but don't know that we can write in mongo or in spring boot

```
 ids = ["1", "5", "7"];
 visibility = true;

array.update({_id: {$in: ids}}, 
   { $set: { visibility } }, 
   {multi: true} 
});
```

need t0o write code in spring boot help on this  thanks